# How to change group id and mountpoint of vagrant default shared folder

Tags: vagrant

When I use `vagrant` with default settings and default `Vagrantfile` it will mount the current host folder into:

```
/vagrant
```

in the guest box. Owner and group of the directory is `vagrant`.

How can I change the mount point and the group id of the default share? Maybe I'm blind but I didn't found anything about that in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the default Vagrant configuration. This should work:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/mymountpoint", :group => "mygroup"
```

How to set a different owner/group for a synced folder is documented [here](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html). For the default configuration, you have instead to check the [source code](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/config/default.rb#L26-28).

Comment: I'm using vagrant 1.0.1. (Should have mentioned this in the question) This version uses the `shared_folder` syntax in Vagrantfile. I tried to override the default share but it didn't work as expected. I figured out that this was because I didn't used the `v-root` id for the share. Now it's working using the following line: `config.vm.share_folder "v-root", "/vagrant", ".", :group => "my-group"`. But however, thanks for your help! Overriding the share in Vagrantfile does the trick!

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need to **change** the mountpoint:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/newmountpoint", group: "newgroup"
```

For more details see the [synced_folders section](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) in the Vagrant docs.